# Apply Function on Dataframe Returns RangeIndex Error

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the code I'm trying to execute but I am getting the error:
`KeyError: 'None of [RangeIndex(start=0, stop=54, step=1)] are in the [columns]'`

I've tried feeding in columns a few ways using dev_cols, feeding in RangeIndex identical to the index of the dataframe. I'm just a bit stuck.

```py
dev_sentences = []
dev_labels = []
for i, (label, words) in enumerate(read_from("dev.txt"), 1):
    dev_sentences.append(words)
    dev_labels.append(label)
    
dev_sentences = pd.DataFrame(dev_sentences)
dev_sentences = dev_sentences.applymap(str)
dev_cols = dev_sentences.columns
print(dev_cols)
print(dev_sentences)

dev = pd.DataFrame()
dev['dev_combined'] = dev[dev_sentences.columns].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected, because `dev` is empty DataFrame, so select by any column(s) failed:

```
dev = pd.DataFrame()
dev[dev_sentences.columns]
```

Need:

```
dev_sentences = pd.DataFrame(dev_sentences).astype(str)
dev = dev_sentences.copy()
dev['dev_combined'] = dev.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Or use `dev_sentences` instead `dev`:

```
dev_sentences = pd.DataFrame(dev_sentences).astype(str)
dev_sentences['dev_combined'] = dev_sentences.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

instead:

```
dev_sentences = pd.DataFrame(dev_sentences)
dev_sentences = dev_sentences.applymap(str)
dev = pd.DataFrame()
dev['dev_combined'] = dev[dev_sentences.columns].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```